# Red Black Tree Height Proof

Tags: red-black-tree

I was reading this Algorithms book, and in the Red Black Tree section, it stated the following lemma: *A red-black tree with n internal nodes has height at most 2 lg(n + 1).*. And then it got into the math part of the proof, and I was lost. Can someone give me a proof that isn't as complicated? I looked it up online, but I didn't seem to find any good websites or videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the properties defining a red-black tree, that all nodes are either red or black, that a red node has two black children and the path from any leaf node to the root will traverse the same number of black nodes.

The simplest case is a tree with no red nodes at all, For such a tree to be a valid red-black tree its bottom level must be completely filled. (Note in the examples I am not showing the leaf nodes).

Take for example:

```
  2b
 / \
1b  3b
```

it has a height of 2, which is floor(log_2(3+1)).

An alternative arrangement simply is not a valid red-black tree:

```
  2b
 / \
1r  3b
```

However the following is also a valid red-black tree and the height is still 2 (note that the colors of 1 2 and 3 could all be flipped, forming a completely filled row of internal black nodes) (floor(log_2(5+1))==2):

```
      4b
    /  \
  2r      5b
  /\
1b  3b
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The last tree looks like the height is 3 to me. If 2 more leafs are added to `5b`, then the calculation becomes `log_2(7+1)) = 3`, but it's the same height as this one presented.

Comment: @Scratte: The usual convention with red-black trees is to consider only the height of black nodes. With a red-black tree of 7 total nodes (red and black both counted) it's possible you have 3 black and four red (root and both children are black, the 4 grandchildren are red), 4 black and 3 red (root is black, with one red and one black child, and the two children of the red child node are black while the two children of the black child node are red), 5 black and two red nodes (root is black with two red children and 4 black grandchildren), or 7 black nodes (all nodes are black).